# Backbone refresh collection with event handler

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using backbone and I'm very new at it, I have a list of products sizes and a list of quantities / prices. When someone selects a different product size, I use backbone to do an ajax call to the server to get me an updated price list.

I'm struggling to get the save function to work so that I can return the updated collection. I will have to pass back a couple params, but for the time being, I'm just trying to get it to save to the backend. I've read save can be used to automatically setup the ajax request.

I'd also only like this to load the template when the li element is clicked, not on page load.

My code

```
var models = {};

models.PriceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({   

})

models.PriceList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {     
        this.productId = options.productId;
    },

    model: models.PriceModel,

    url: function() {
           return '../product/pricing/' + this.productId + '.json'
        }  

});
```

View

```
var PriceView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#product-module',

    template: Handlebars.compile($("#priceTemplate").html()),

    events: {
        "click #product-dimensions li": "dimensionClicked",
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.find('#product-quantities').html( this.template(this.collection.toJSON()));
    },

    dimensionClicked: function(event, callback){        
        this.collection.save({},{
              success: function(model, data){
                  console.log('success')
                  this.collection.fetch();
              },
              error: function(model, response) {
                  console.log('error! ' + response);
              }
          });
    },

});
```

Page

```
<script>   
    var prices = new models.PriceList({productId:${productInstance.id}});
    var priceView = new PriceView({collection: prices});
<%--        prices.fetch({reset: true});--%>
</script>
```

The error I'm getting.

> TypeError: this.collection.save is not a function
>
> this.collection.save({},{

How do I pass back a couple of params and then refresh the template?

Comment: Did you mean to use collection.sync ?

Comment: Roman, could you please explain? I'm not entirely sure what I should be using, this is my first time using backbone.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. What does dimensionClicked do? I believe that you have to get the dimension that was clicked with $(event.currentTarget) and then do something about it. Are you supposed to change url based on it? Then you should assign collection.url and call collection.fetch().

Comment: Also, I don't need to pass the product collection back to the server, I only need to pass the product id and the size id to the server, from there I'll perform some price calculations and the return my quantity collection..

Comment: Two radio groups, one has product size, the other has product quantity, when you click a different product size, you will fire the method dimensionclicked which will then send a product id and the dimension value to the backend where an updated quantity / price collection will be returned.

Comment: I shouldn't have to change the url and I'll use some js to get the product size radio value. I'm just not sure how to save the model and return the collection.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use

```
this.collection.fetch({data: {customParm : searchData}, reset: true});
```